# Как сделать карусель (отзывов) используя FancyBox 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

Не в виде всплывающего окна, а именно как карусел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хочу нагружать сайт лишними библиотеками. 
На сайте уже применяю FancyBox 3. Хотелось бы и для блока отзывов его задействовать

+
 у FancyBox есть функция слайдера/карусели, но только в всплывающем (модальном)окне. Вопрос в том, как только её задействовать?

Comment: А разве fancybox имеют функции карусели? Кажется нет, подключайте доп. библиотеку типа owl-carousel

Comment: у fancybox нету функции слайдера .

Comment: у FancyBox есть функция слайдера/карусели, но только в всплывающем (модальном)окне. Вопрос в том, как только её задействовать?

Comment: В fancybox не сделаешь такое, надо использовать другие библиотеки.